# Inserting list elements to vector, getting additional unwanted values C++

Tags: c++, list, vector, insert

In my C++ script, I want to insert some elements of a list into a vector (from the beginning of list to a specific position "it"), and then try to add the vector at the top of the list and keeping the same order of the vector but I get unwanted additional elements in the vector.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iterator>   
#include <vector>       
#include <list>        

int main() {

std::list<int> mylist;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    mylist.push_back(i * 10);

for (std::list<int>::iterator i = mylist.begin(); i <= mylist.end(); ++i) {
    std::cout << *i << ", ";
}

std::cout << std::endl;

std::advance(it, 6);
std::cout << "The 6th element in mylist is: " << *it << std::endl;

// The vector that will contain mylist elements
std::vector<int> intAdeplacer;
intAdeplacer.insert(intAdeplacer.end(), mylist.begin(), it);

std::cout << std::endl;


std::cout << "Nombre d'éléments dans le vecteur : " << intAdeplacer.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;

// see the content of the vector
std::cout << "Le vecteur de deplacement contient  : " << std::endl;

for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = intAdeplacer.begin();
        i <= intAdeplacer.end(); ++i) {
    std::cout << *i << ", ";
}
```

I get this output:

> Le vecteur de deplacement contient  : 
>   0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 134985,

134985 is not wanted..

```
// Insert in front of the list the values of the vector and keeping the same order of elements in the vector

for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = intAdeplacer.end();
        i >= intAdeplacer.begin(); --i) {
    mylist.push_front(*i);
}

std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;

std::cout << "nouvelle composition de mylist : " << std::endl;

for (std::list<int>::const_iterator j = mylist.begin(); j != mylist.end();
        ++j) {
    std::cout << *j << ", ";
}

std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;


// erasing the added elements from mylist

std::list<int>::iterator debut = mylist.begin();
std::list<int>::iterator fin = mylist.end();

std::advance(fin, 6);
mylist.erase(debut, fin);

for (std::list<int>::iterator j = mylist.begin(); j <= mylist.end(); ++j) {
    std::cout << *j << ", ";
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: This `i <= intAdeplacer.end()` should be `i < intAdeplacer.end()`. Look up any example of iterating over a vector.

Comment: but I need to see all the content of the vector to be sure of the elements that will be added to the list.

Comment: Normally people call `script` file for interpreted languages like python, shell, basic etc. C++ produces executable, not script.

Comment: As I said, look up any example of iterating over a vector.

Comment: During first iteration, the iterator won't refer to anything because end() is just past the end of the vector. Try using reverse_iterator and test for != intAdeplacer.end() in for loop.

Comment: examples should be in English, not in French

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `it` is an iterator pointing at the 6th element of your list,  the following [`insert()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) will insert from `begin()` (included) to `it` (excluded) into the vector:

```
intAdeplacer.insert(intAdeplacer.end(), mylist.begin(), it);
```

So you'll have only 5 elements, from 0 to 40.  Unfortunately your printing loop does include the `end()` of the vector, which is out of range.  This is why you get this strange trailing number.

Just correct your loop into:

```
for (auto i = intAdeplacer.begin(); i != intAdeplacer.end(); ++i) {
    std::cout << *i << ", ";
}
```

Or consider this alternate [*range-for*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) syntax:

```
for (auto &element: intAdeplacer) {
    std::cout << element << ", ";
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer ! I have another question : How can I avoid adding the end of the vector to the list ?

Comment: If you start from the end, you have to check that your''ve not reached the begin, and instead of decrementing the iterator at the end of the for loop, you should decrement it in the loop before using it.  In this [online example](http://ideone.com/dr4SSu), I've edited the code with all the different remarks put together.

Comment: Thank you very much Christophe